# Is it possible to call a different overloaded function in the same function?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

I'm trying to write a simple extension to XCTestCase so that I don't have to unwrap everything when checking true or false. It's like the normal XCTAssertTrue but takes a `Bool?` instead. (XCTAssertEqual takes optionals, so it's odd this one doesn't)

```
// Currently have this
XCTAssertTrue(thing?.isValid ?? false)
XCTAssertFalse(thing?.isValid ?? true)

// I want this to work on optionals
XCTAssertTrue(thing?.isValid)
XCTAssertFalse(thing?.isValid)
```

```
extension XCTestCase {
    func XCTAssertTrue(_ expression: Bool?, _ message: String = "", file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        if let unwrapped = expression {
            XCTAssertTrue(unwrapped, message, file: file, line: line)
        }
        XCTFail("It was nil.", file: file, line: line)
    }
    
    func XCTAssertFalse(_ expression: Bool?, _ message: String = "", file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        if let unwrapped = expression {
            XCTAssertFalse(unwrapped, message, file: file, line: line)
        }
        XCTFail("It was nil.", file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

Problem is it calls itself instead of the **other** XCTAssertTrue, which has different parameters.  But why can't it tell the difference?

I can fix it by renaming them to something like XCTAssertOptionalTrue, but I'd like them to have the same name for ease of use. Is this possible?

Comment: I always do `XCTestEqual(foo, true)` because it's easier to read and understand when I skim over my tests. So in your case I would write `XCTAssertEqual(thing?.isValid, true)` or `XCTAssertEqual(thing?.isValid, false)`. I don't know about any draw back doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t write an overload, because this is Objective C under the hood so there are no overloads! Anyway, you're doing *way* too much work here. The goal apparently is: "Given an Optional Bool, fail if nil, otherwise unwrap and assert true or false". The way to say that is:

```
XCTAssertTrue(try XCTUnwrap(thing?.isValid)) // or XCTAssertFalse
```

Observe that this assumes that your `test...` function is a `throws` function. Well, if it isn't, it should be! The ability of a `test...` function to throw is a very important feature; throwing causes the test to fail instantly, which is just what you want.

Comment: This is an interesting way to do it still using XCTAssertTrue. But it seems my example has distracted from my core question, which was why an overloaded function named XCTAssertTrue calls itself infinitely instead of calling the "other" core library function named XCTAssertTrue. They have the same name, but the parameters are different types. So normally the compiler can figure that out?

Comment: I may have figured part of it out. I tried to overload _any_ function declared in an XCTestCase subclass, and it didn't work. `func get(foo: String) { }` and `func get(foo: Int) { }` got the error "...conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector". Odd because if I write those _not_ in a unit test file, they can exist fine with no error.

Comment: Oh, I see. Because this is Objective C under the hood so there are no overloads! I’ll add that to my answer. Anyway... Don’t try to mess with XCTestCase. If you want to write your own utility, write it. You can build your own assertion using XCTIssue.

Comment: Just so I understand fully, the reason XCTestCase is Objective-C under the hood, is more than simply because it inherits from NSObject? Because I can write a subclass of NSObject in Swift with overloaded functions as long as I don't mark them with @objc

Comment: That's correct. Swift has overloaded methods, but if you were to expose more than one of those to Objective-C with `@objc`, the compiler would barf because Objective-C doesn't do overloads. In this case, though, you're overloading an _inherited_ Objective-C method, so you can run but you can't hide it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The XCTest assertions are no longer methods. They are standalone functions we can invoke from anywhere. This makes it much easier to write helper assertions, as they no longer require an object.

```
// No extension. And don't name them XCT, they're not in XCTest.
func assertMyThing(thing: Thing, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
   // …
}
```

In your case, there's simply no need. To check the value of an optional Bool use what @dasdom showed in the comments: use XCTAssertEqual.

```
XCTAssertEqual(thing?.isValid, true)
```

Upon failure, this reports the failing value. In this case, the report will tell us if the actual value was false or nil.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no longer methods" and "no longer require an object". I made an extension so they can be reused by other XCTest test files.

Comment: The assertions are now free functions, not XCTestCase methods. They don't live in XCTestCase, and neither should your helper assertions. As long as you can `import XCTest` you can call the built-in assertions. …Does that help? Let me know if I should elaborate.